# Which is the most efficient way to run a Monero full node on a bare-metal hypervisor?

Tags: full-node, server

I would like to install a full Monero node on a Proxmox hypervisor. I was wondering what was the best solution (virtual server, LXC container or docker container on top of a VM) and if there were already available pre-settled / trusted solutions.

Thanks to all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578039/difference-between-kvm-and-lxc

Answer (score 1):

> Which is the most efficient way to run a Monero full node on a bare-metal hypervisor?

The term "efficiency" can have a couple of meanings in this context. Efficient usage of resources, efficient time to install etc.

> I was wondering what was the best solution (virtual server, LXC container or docker container on top of a VM)

In the context of efficient usage of system resources, LXC containers are light-weight, making use of the host OS. KVM by contrast is essentially running a whole separate OS. Therefore you could say LXC is more "efficient" than KVM. More answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578039/difference-between-kvm-and-lxc) though.

What is the "best solution" is very much determined by your intended use-case and what else needs to run on the hardware. However, in the case of simply running a single Monero daemon, I can't immediately see the case for a full-on KVM solution.

> and if there were already available pre-settled / trusted solutions

Trust is a sliding scale. I would say the most *trusted* setup is to build the daemon from source and install that on whatever system/setup you choose. Failing that, there is also the option of downloading pre-compiled [releases](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/releases) from the official GitHub repository and lastly there is a [Docker file](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/Dockerfile), should prefer running Docker.

Comment: I'm currently testing an LXC container with source compiled on it, a VM with binaries and I'm planning to use a docker image in the next days. Looking at resource usage, the LXC container is incredibly lightweight.